# Visualize with OpenCV image read by tensorflow

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

With the code below I read the same image with OpenCV and with Tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

def get_image(image_path):
    """Reads the jpg image from image_path.
    Returns the image as a tf.float32 tensor
    Args:
        image_path: tf.string tensor
    Reuturn:
        the decoded jpeg image casted to float32
    """
    return tf.image.convert_image_dtype(
        tf.image.decode_jpeg(
            tf.read_file(image_path), channels=3),
        dtype=tf.uint8)


path = "./images/2010_006748.jpg"
original_image = cv2.imread(path)

image_tensor = get_image(tf.constant(path))
# convert to uint8
image_tensor = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_tensor, dtype=tf.uint8)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    image = sess.run(image_tensor)

cv2.imshow("tf", image)
cv2.imshow("original", original_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

As you can see from the image, ther's a difference between the image read by OpenCV (right colors) and by Tensorflow (wrong colors).

[image: tensorflow vs opencv]

I tried to normalize the colors of the Tensorflow image using `cv2.normalize(image, image, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8UC3)` but nothing changed.

I've also tryed to read the image as `tf.uint8` (removing the initiall cast to `tf.float32`) but no changes.

How can I display the image read with Tensorflow, using OpenCV properly?

Comment: it looks like the red and blue channels are swapped, what is the default order for reading RGB images in tensorflow? is it BGR or RGB?

Comment: You're right! Tensorflow format is RGB whilst OpenCV format is BGR. So, how can I convert between these 2 color spaces?

Comment: I'm just looking at the docs now, you may have to swap the channels yourself after loading as I can't see any options to specify the channel order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
bgr_img = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```